# Why does this show Log can't be extended to whole $\mathbb{C}^*$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, continuity, logarithms, branch-cuts

Why does the following show Log can't be extended to whole $\mathbb{C}^*$?
[image]

Here's another proof which I think I understand, though I'm not sure what's the connection between the two proofs:
[image]

I believe the 2nd proof says because approaching from different directions yield different possible values for Log, so Log can't be made continuous. (please tell me if my understanding is wrong)

But one I don't see the connection between the two proofs, and two I don't understand the 1st proof.

I would be happy if anyone could help explain them.

Comment: Oy. The first is nonsense. Indeed, $e^z$ is continuous. (They omitted the logs, didn’t they?) The second gives a justification, provided you take $\epsilon>0$ and interpret $\pm$ very carefully. Not ideally written, either.

Comment: Please don't use images in posts on this site—they make searching harder.

Comment: @TedShifrin Do you mean the 1st proof doesnt really prove "Log can't be extended"?

Comment: It meant to, but it certainly does not. The limits it claims are unequal are equal, are they not?

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what book did you find that egregious typographical (?) error?

Comment: What Greg said. OTOH, it can be helpful to include an image in addition to the transcribed text if you suspect that the passage contains a typo. However, you need to give proper attribution for any material posted on Stack Exchange that you didn't create. Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing